# Disabling tail.sh for specific server ( or environment )?

Tags: javascript, meteor

While testing my meteor app i keep receiving emails saying my application went offline.

How does i disable this feature for an specific environment or hostname ( for instance, "localhost" ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this feature should be disabled for dev environments. It will probably be done so :]

Not sure if this counts as an answer. I made a GH ticket to track the progress until its updated: https://github.com/Tarang/Meteor-Analytics/issues/28

Comment: i should have opened an issue! instead of a question! so this is a perfect answer!